# Monte Carlo Gaussian Function with loops

Tags: python, function, loops

I am attempting my homework for class and having trouble making this function. In our lab we created monte_carlo_chisquared like this:

```
import math

def chisquared(x, degrees_of_freedom):
    k = degrees_of_freedom
    return (1 / ( (2 ** (k / 2)) * (math.gamma(k/2)) )) * (x ** ((k/2)- 1)) * (math.e ** (-x/2))
    
def plotcho(x: list, degrees_of_freedom: int):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    y = [chisquared(xi, degrees_of_freedom) for xi in x]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
    pass

def under_curve(x, y, degrees_of_freedom):
    """
    >>> under_curve(1, 0.15, 3)
    True
    
    >>> under_curve(4, 0.2, 3)
    False
    
    """
    fx = chisquared(x, degrees_of_freedom)
    if (0 <= y) and (y <= fx):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def less_than(x,b):
    return x < b

def monte_carlo_chisquared(b: float, degrees_of_freedom: int, n: int):
    import numpy as np
    x = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=b, size=n)
    y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=b, size=n)
    
    i = 0 
    ndartsunder = 0
    ndarts = 0 
    for xi in x:
        yi = y[i]
        
        if less_than(xi, b):
            ndartsunder = ndartsunder + 1*under_curve(xi, yi, degrees_of_freedom)
            ndarts += 1
        i += 1
    prob_under_curve = ndartsunder / ndarts
    return b*prob_under_curve
```

Now I need to create monte_carlo_gaussian. So far I have this but it does not work. I copied and pasted monte_carlo_chisquared and made a few changes, but I think I need to make even more, I'm just not sure what to do.

[image]

```
import math

def gaussian(x):
    return ((1 / math.sqrt(2 * math.pi) * math.e) ** ( (-x ** 2) / 2))

# Problem 2.

def under_curve(x, y):
    if 0 <= y <= gaussian(x):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Problem 3.

def greater_than(x, a):
    if x > a:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Problem 4.

def less_than(x, b):
    if x < b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Problem 5.

def monte_carlo_gaussian(a, b, n):
    import numpy as np
    x = np.random.uniform(low=a, high=b, size=n)
    y = np.random.uniform(low=a, high=b, size=n)
    
    i = 0 
    ndartsunder = 0
    ndarts = 0 
    for xi in x:
        yi = y[i]
        
        if less_than(xi, b) is True and greater_than(xi, a) is True:
            ndartsunder = ndartsunder + 1 * under_curve(xi, yi)
            ndarts += 1
        i += 1
    prob_under_curve = ndartsunder / ndarts
    return b * prob_under_curve
```

I would appreciate any help/tips to get me going in the right direction for how to create this function. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know how, in theory, this function should work? If not, then you haven't got a question that is on-topic for Stack Overflow yet. If you do, and have a particular problem when programming it, then your post should contain a description of said problem.

Comment: FWIW. It looks like you have the parenthesis incorrect on you gaussian function. If you plot it, it should only peak around 0.4. Something like `(math.e ** ((-x ** 2) / 2)) / math.sqrt(2 * math.pi)` is going to work better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the lines:

```
        if less_than(xi, b) is True and greater_than(xi, a) is True:
            ndartsunder = ndartsunder + 1 * under_curve(xi, yi)
            ndarts += 1
```

You want to sum the values calculated by the gaussian function. But your gaussian function is returning true or false, and not the value given by the gaussian function.

Comment: Im not quite sure what I should do for this. Do I change the if line?

Comment: You should change your under_curve(x, y) function. There are more things that need to be done to fix this, but that is your first step. Then you should print out the result and compare to the expected result to see what you need to do next.